# What is the meaning of SP and HT in separators defention

Tags: http, header, http-headers

In the the HTTP headers [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) I need to understand the definition of token:

> token          = 1*
>          separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
>                         | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
>                         | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
>                         | "{" | "}" | SP | HT

I do not get what is the meaning of SP and HT at the end of the separators list? How to write this in a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are defined in the very same RFC:

> SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
>   HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>